# How to learn Sharepoint in a week?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new in Sharepoint 2010. I have to finish a CMS project within 10 days in Sharepoint.

Please suggest me good share point material or video training(free) to learn share point quicker. And how to download and install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to set your expectations. Learning to develop for SharePoint is not something you learn in a matter of days. To become a really effective SharePoint developer takes a matter on months.

Here are some resources that will help you get started.

[SharePoint Developer Center > Learn > Get Started Developing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513148.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010 Developer Training Course](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/)

[Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx)